# how to write css for specific page in asp.net mvc3

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to reference a .css file on a razor view?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5021552/how-to-reference-a-css-file-on-a-razor-view)

How to add page specfic css in asp.net mvc3 views but i dont want to add

css for page in header  , **is there any other solution ???**

Comment: Use a `@section` - see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5021552/how-to-reference-a-css-file-on-a-razor-view)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could define a section in your `_Layout.cshtml`:

```
<head>
    ...
    <link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/Site.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    @RenderSection("styles", false)
    ...
</head>
```

and then inside your view override this section to include the specific CSS for the given view:

```
@section styles {
    <link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/index.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
}
```

Answer (score 0):

using jquery you can do it.

```
var cssselection;
if(x)
  cssselection=default.css
 else
   cssselection=first.css

$(function() {
   $('link').first().attr('href', cssselection);
});
```

Comment: http://i.stack.imgur.com/ssRUr.gif

Comment: @Darin my answer is not relevant. But it seems funny.. :)

Comment: Well seemed relevant to me. jQuery is not the solution to all problems.