# Hide vertical scrollbar for specific page in mvc 4

Tags: html, css, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

Using following css code I can disable vertical scroll bar for whole mvc 4 project view files.

```
body {
 overflow-y: hidden!important;
}
```

But how to disable vertical scrollbar for specific cshtml view page

Comment: Mode the CSS inside those specific views. If you target specific scenarios, you could add the text using Razor syntax. If you target specific HTML objects, set their ids or classes as selector instead of `body`.

Comment: can you explain more

Comment: You can use specific selectors pertaining to those views rather than using the body selector.

Comment: @AndreiV can you give exmple

Comment: Check out [this example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5021552/how-to-reference-a-css-file-on-a-razor-view) and also [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5110028/add-css-or-js-files-to-layout-head-from-views-or-partial-views).

Answer (score 1):

you have two main solutons: with CSS, you select one body or div with class selector ( see [selector class](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_class.asp) for more informations), or you use JQUERY/JS

First solution : tou can wrap the razor page with

```
<div class="hideVerticalScrollbar">
content here
</div>
```

or directly use this body:

```
<body class="hideVerticalScrollbar">
    content here
</body >
```

and then use this rule:

```
.hideVerticalScrollbar{
 overflow-y: hidden!important;
}
```

OR second possibility, you can use jquery/javascript

```
$("body:has(div.hideVerticalScrollbar)").css( "overflow-y: hidden!important;" );
```