# Can I use CSS in MVC 4?

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc-4

I have some stylesheets with me which can be reused. Can I use this existing CSS files in my mvc 4 application to get styling to my application

Comment: Yes, you can use CSS to style web pages.  Why would you think you couldn't?

Comment: it actually comes with bootstrap an a great mechanism to concatenate and minify all your styles. is in the app_start/BundleConfig.cs

Answer (score 2):

Yes, why wouldn't you? MVC 4 is still HTML based and supports css, javascript, ...

Some links that may help you get started:

- http://www.w3schools.com/aspnet/mvc_layout.asp
- [How to reference a .css file on a razor view?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5021552/how-to-reference-a-css-file-on-a-razor-view)
- http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/forums/thread/230865/mvc4-css-style-sheet.aspx

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Indra you can use HTML, CSS, jquery in any web applications. Asp.net MVC is used to build a web application so you can use them here. Similarly its the same for other technologies like Java, php, phyton etc if its a web application then HTML, CSS, jquery can be used since ultimately we will view the application in any of the browser and any page in the browser will be a HTML page only, HTML pages support CSS and Jquery.