# How to make a valid static address inside JavaScript or CSS files in ASP.Net MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I'm a little bit new to ASP.Net MVC, I started to migrate from WebForm to MVC but I faced with an issue in addressing in JavaScript or CSS files.

Imagine I have a `sample.css` file in which there is an address:

`background: url("../image.jpg");`

It works truly in WebForm since `..` in WebForm takes address a level back but it in MVC address contains of controller and action so `..` doesn't mean the same. Although it works sometimes.

How should I solve the matter? What is the right approach?

Answer (score 0):

I believe this answer will help you [How to reference a .css file on a razor view?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5021552/how-to-reference-a-css-file-on-a-razor-view) also search up **bundling** in MVC5

Comment: Thanks for your replay, but all the samples in the given link, are placed in `.cshtml` file where Razor can acts, what I'm asking about is when it's inside `.css` or `.js` files.